# Erlang function that returns two values

Tags: list, function, erlang

I have Erlang function that returns the last element of a list

```
lastElement([H|[]]) ->H;
lastElement([H|T]) ->lastElement(T).
```

and a function that returns a list without last element

```
withoutLastElement([H|[]], Result) ->Result;
withoutLastElement([H|T]) ->withoutLastElement(T, [H|Result]).
```

so i browse the same list for two times, and for more efficiency i want to do only a function that returns the last element of a list and returns this list without this element in one browse, this is easy in another language but i can't do that in Erlang so any help and thank you all.

Comment: Use Accumulator. It is very useful for optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd usually return the two values in a tuple:

```
list_and_last(List) ->
    list_and_last(List, []).

list_and_last([H], Result) ->
    {H, Result};
list_and_last([H|T], Result) ->
    list_and_last(T, [H|Result]).
```

Calling `list_and_last` with `[1,2,3]` returns `{3,[2,1]}`.

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang you can return a tuple, so you simply define a tuple with the last element and the list:

```
... -> {last_element, list}
```

You retrieve the value with pattern matching:

```
{Element, List} = last_element_and_new_list(The_List)
```

The last element and list will be bound to the respective variables. Note that you can return more than two values in a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reverse the list:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[Last | Rest] = lists:reverse(List)
```